# Should we install a docker image from Docker Hub at the begining?

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I want to introduce docker for my development environment.

I wanted to create a docker image from a existing linux machine.
But,I could not find a official method on docker documentation.
https://docs.docker.com/learn/ 
(I know there are some ways on the Internet to create a docker image like converting .iso file to .tar.gz file.
However,it's not official)

After that,I installed a docker image of Debian OS from Docker Hub with 'docker pull' command.
However,I could not find a correct version of Debian OS I wanted.

So, to get a OS of a correct kernel verion and a correct Debian os version, 
after I install a docker image from Docker Hub, should I customize it?
Is there any way as an official manner to create a docker image from a exisiting linux machine?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should be looking at Hashicorp's packer, it would allow  you to build your own Docker base images, from whatever base you wish.

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html